# How to clip textblock inside proportional grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, clipping

In a UserControl that's inside a ListBox, I've got a TextBlock with proportional width (Width="*") inside a Grid that I want to take the remaining width of the grid, but whenever I resize the ListBox to a size that would clip that TextBlock's content I get a scroll bar. How can I clip the TextBlock width so that I don't get an horizontal scroll bar? Ideally clipping it with ellipsis.

EDIT: Forgot to mention the ListBox.

Comment: Grid clips the content by default, and doesn't have any scroll bar support. Are you using a ListBox or ScrollViewer anywhere? Some code would be useful. The default behavior of a TextBlock in a Grid sounds like just what you want. Are you using a TextBOX (this has scroll bar support)?

Comment: Yes, that said grid is inside a UserControl inside a Listbox.

Comment: Off topic: This is the 40,000th `xaml` question, congratulations OP. There are no prizes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listbox is scrolling because it's default behavior is to have `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto`.

Try setting this property to disabled:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

As for clipping to an ellipse, this is more complex. You can clip to an ellipsis quite easily using the `Clip` property:

```
            <TextBlock Text="Some very long thing that I'm putting in here to clip" Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock.Clip>
                    <EllipseGeometry Center="100,8" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="8" />
                </TextBlock.Clip>
            </TextBlock>
```

However, to keep the Center, RadiusX and RadiusY in order you'll have to bind it to the height and width of the text box (perhaps using a converter to half these values).